# Can not inject $scope and constants into controller of abstract state with ui router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am using angular 1.3.11 with latest ui router.

When I inject the $scope or constants into my DateplannerController via:

```
'use strict';
angular.module('test').controller('DateplannerController', function (stateConfiguration, $scope, $state) {

});
```

then the stateConfiguration AND $scope are not defined.

Why?

```
   .state('main.projects.selected.dates', {
            url: '/planner',
            abstract: true,
            views: {
              'menu@': {
                templateUrl: '../views/menu.html',
                controller: 'MenuController'
              },
              'content@': {
                templateUrl: '../views/dateplanner/dateplanner.html',
                controller: 'DateplannerController'
              }
            }
          })



    'use strict';
    angular
      .module('test', ['ui.router', 'ui.grid', 'ui.grid.selection',
        'ui.grid.resizeColumns', 'ui.bootstrap', 'angularMoment', 'LocalStorageModule', 'textAngular', 'angularModalService'] )
      .constant('stateConfiguration', {
            state1: 'bla'
      })
```

Comment: Any errors in your console?

Comment: no errors in the console!

Answer (score 0):

I think you're overlooking one thing pertaining to an abstract state:

> An abstract state can have child states but can not get activated itself. An 'abstract' state is simply a state that can't be transitioned to. It is activated implicitly when one of its descendants are activated.

See: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-%26-Nested-Views#abstract-states

My guess is you're trying to navigate to `/planner` which won't work. You've got add a child state and navigate to that URL. Hard to say what goes wrong based on the code you supplied. I'de suggest checking the examples on the page which i linked above.

Comment: No I do not try to navigate to /planner. My routing works for month no problem with that. I route to /planner/day or /planner/week etc... ;-)